# Turkish character splitting

Tags: java, split

I have a person name string which is include Turkish characters like `Saime Çiloğlu Akdan`. What I want to do drop middle names from the string. As a result, string should be `Saime Akdan`. I tried several things but I always gettng `java.lang.NullPointerException`. The reason is because of the turkish characters. I think `split` function doesn't recognize the Turkish characters.

```java
// String name = input_row.PERSON_NAME.toLowerCase(new Locale("tr", "TR")).toString();
String name = new String(input_row.PERSON_NAME.getBytes("UTF-8"));
String[] names = name.split("\\s+");

if (names.length == 3) {
    output_row.PERSON_EMAIL = names[0] + "." + names[2] + "@metro-tr.com";
} else {
    output_row.PERSON_EMAIL = names[0] + "." + names[1] + "@metro-tr.com";
}
```

Comment: Where's the output_row / input_row variable defined? If nowhere, then this is the source of your exception. I also assume you are missing a '=' in the first if statement's body

Comment: `output_row` comes from data flow, means equally `Saime Çiloğlu Akdan`

Comment: On which line does the NPE happen?

Comment: For future reference - it is better to provide a distilled code sample, you could provide those variables as statically defined before your code sample. I think Gaurava already answered your question too.

Comment: It is not related to the question but... Dropping the middle names? It sounds not so good idea at all. Better a new field without middle name if it is really needed (dropping because of having Turkish character is also a little bit rare).

Comment: dear @kocko, I can't see because only Enterprise edition of Talend studio has setting breakpoints. I can only see trace output.

Answer (score 2):

Not the Turkish characters are the reason for the NPE, because

```
String name = "Saime Çiloğlu Akdan";
String[] names = name.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(names[0] + " "+ names[2]);
```

works fine, just as intended.

**PS:** I do not really understand this line:

```
new String(input_row.PERSON_NAME.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

`input_row.PERSON_NAME` is the String what you need, it is beyond me why are you converting it to byte array, then back to `String`.

Comment: Dear friend, I am using Talend Data Integration tool. The line that you mentioned comes from the another component which means all component connected each other, like data flow. input_row.PERSON_NAME is a flow line name.

Comment: So what type it is? The `getBytes()` method suggests `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = "Saime Çiloğlu Akdan";
String[] names = name.split(" ");

if (names.length == 3) {
    System.out.println(names[0] + "." + names[2] + "@metro-tr.com");
} else {
    //output_row.PERSON_EMAIL = names[0] + "." + names[1] + "@metro-tr.com";
}
```

O/P: `Saime.Akdan@metro-tr.com`

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the string into a function that copy only alpha-numerical characters into another string, then return it and use it.

So far, if the string contains a word with any Turkish characters, you don't copy this word. Otherwise, you do.

This way, your function will return a string without any non-conventional (for the standard ascii table) character in it.